# Possible to close a Modal Dialog from code behind?

Tags: 2010, modal-dialog

I am popping up a Custom Application Page using a call to SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog.  Is there a way that I can close the dialog from the code behind after a user clicks a button?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a solution.  Add this to the end of the button click event:

```
Context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
Context.Response.Flush();
Context.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also add the `SP.UI.ModalDialog.close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)` event on your button or otherwise make some javascript logic that triggers this event if no errors occured.

Examples 1:

```
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" OnClientClick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)" />
```

Example 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// In case you use jquery ajax for some kind of postback
$.ajax({type: "POST", 
url: some_url, 
data: {},
contentType: ...,
success: function() {SP.UI.ModalDialog.close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);},
error: function() {SP.UI.ModalDialog.close(SP.UI.DialogResult.invalid);}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to close the Modal Dialog from code-behind.

Simply add the below code to your button click event and you are done.

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["IsDlg"] != null)
            {
                context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup()</script>");
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better still create an extension method on the Page object

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Closes the SP Dialog down.  Note this will only work when the button triggering the close action does not reside in an Update Panel
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="Page"></param>
 public static void CloseSPDialog(this Page Page)
 {
     Page.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
     Page.Response.Flush();
     Page.Response.End();
 }
```

And call like this

```
void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff here
    Page.CloseSPDialog();
}
```